# Get input from button and validate if its correct or wrong

Tags: java, validation, input, jframe, jbutton

I'm creating an ATM machine with pin function. The problem is I want to get the input from the button when its pressed by the user and validate if its correct or wrong. When the button is pressed,  it will store the result in the string. It will then be used to validate if its correct or wrong. For example: User A pressed 012345. Each number will then be stored to another string for validation. The string is then compared to the pin.

**public class atmMachine:**

```
int numberPinButton = 10;
String pin = "012345";
String zero, one, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine;
```

**public atmMachine:**

```
panel = new JPanel();
pinButton = new JButton[numberPinButton];
for(int i = 0; i < numberPinButton; i++) {
    pinButton[i] = new JButton("" + i);
    pinButton[i].addActionListener(this);
    panel.add(pinButton[i]);
}
enterButton = new JButton("Enter");
enterButton.addActionListener(this);
panel.add(enterBtn);
panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Enter your pin:"));
add(panel, BorderLayout.WEST);
```

**public void actionPerformed:**

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        if(event.getSource() == pinButton[0]) {
            zero = "0";
        } else if(e.getSource() == pinButton[1]) {
            one = "1";
        } else if(e.getSource() == pinButton[2]) {
            two = "2";
        } else if(e.getSource() == pinButton[3]) {
            three = "3";
        } else if(e.getSource() == pinButton[4]) {
            four = "4";;
        } else if(e.getSource() == pinButton[5]) {
            five = "5";
        } else if(e.getSource() == pinButton[6]) {
            six = "6";
        } else if(e.getSource() == pinButton[7]) {
            seven = "7";
        } else if(e.getSource() == pinButton[8]) {
            eight = "8";
        } else if(e.getSource() == pinButton[9]) {
            nine = "9";
        }

        if(e.getSource() == enterBtn) {
            if(???.equals(pin)) {
                System.out.println("Correct");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Wrong");
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: what is the "problem" exactly??

Comment: Get a clear idea for what you want the program to do, eg: each button will add a digit to the string of pin digits, and when the user presses OK the digits entered will be validated. Then we can help with problems.

Comment: @andy256 Added these 2 lines but it outputs nulls. **String abc = zero+one+two+three+four+five+six+seven+eight+nine;
            System.out.print(abc);**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have an instance variable-

```
StringBuffer userKeyString = new StringBuffer();
```

On action performed, append any digit button pressed-

```
userKeyString.append(event.getActionCommand());
```

On action performed, if enter pressed-

```
if(event.getSource() == enterBtn){

    if(pin.equals(userKeyString.toString()){

        // Correct pin

    } else {

        // Incorrect pin

    }

    userKeyString.setLength(0); // Clear the buffer for next input and validation

} else {

    userKeyString.append(event.getActionCommand());

}
```

You should set the action commands of your buttons-

```
for(int i = 0; i < numberPinButton; i++) {
    pinButton[i] = new JButton("" + i);
    pinButton[i].setActionCommand(String.valueOf(i));
    pinButton[i].addActionListener(this);
    panel.add(pinButton[i]);
}
```

Comment: It outputs:0
01
012
0123
01234
012345
012345Enter
Wrong

Comment: @Demon Lemon You should set your button action command. e.g. digitZeroBtn.setActionCommand("0");

Comment: @DemonLemon Please see the modified answer.

Comment: Still outputs: 012345Enter

Comment: @DemonLemon You are not supposed to append to userKeyString when enter is pressed. You should only append when a digit is pressed. See the edited answer.

Comment: Thanks! Finally got it working perfectly. Any idea how could I reset userKeyString.toString() so that when the user enters the pin wrongly he/she can re-enter them?

Answer (score 0):

You can declare String pin as a field like:

```
String pin;
```

then in action performed you append to it (pseudo code)

```
actionPerformed(...){
    pin += keyPressed;
    if(pin.length > 5){
        validatePin(pin);
    }
}
```

Does this answer your question?

But to be honest I would suggest against validation in the action performed method. I'd try to validate the pin after all the numbers were inserted. This way you can save a bit on performance and the code would be more readable. The performance isn't an issue here but it's a good practice as you would check the pin 6 times here instead of just once outside the actionPerformed method.

Like:

```
for(int i = 0; i < pinLength; i++){
    waitForUserToPressButtonOrTimeout();
    appendToCurrentPin();
}
validatePin();
```

Or let the user simply press another button after entering the pin code and link validation to that button. But I think using String pin field and appending to it is an answer to your question.